# Objective C: Query regarding Cell Setup containing variable number of labels

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uilabel

I have a design query regarding how a cell should be set up if I have a variable number of labels to be added to the cell content's view. For example for cell 1 I need 2 labels and cell 2 I need 5 labels etc

How can I add this to my cell setup in the most effective manner? Do I attempt to run through the array of objects to determine and set the number of labels in the "cell = nil" or do it outside the loop?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    int row = [indexPath row];

    CustomCell* cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease]; 

        //Do I create the labels here by looping through the array?
        [cell setupCell];

    }

    //Or do I create them here instead??
    [cell loadContentAndHeight];

    return cell;

}
```

Currently, I am not doing the creation of labels within the loop of 'cell = nil', instead all creation (alloc/init) of labels are done outside the loop.

```
for(SomeClass *instance in someObjectArray)
{
    OHAttributLabel *label = [[OHAttributeLabel alloc]initWith........
    [cell.contentview addsubview:label];
}
```

The issue here is that in the allocation tool (in instruments), I observed that the retainCount of my label keeps increasing (see screenshot). I believe that is due to the fact that I am creating new labels everytime a cell is being re-used.

[image]

I believe in the long run, this will impact the performance of my table scroll. Can anyone advise me on the most effective way to implement a variable number of labels in a cell?

EDIT: Added screenshot of leak tool

I checked the leak tool and it doesn't show where I am leaking in the tableview code. All the items leaking are not relevant to the table I am concerned. Is it the way I am running the tool?
[image]

Comment: you're leaking memory in for loop, you call alloc and where is release? in next iteration you will loose ability to release it. in instruments switch to Leaks to see what was leaked.

Comment: @alahcur, I checked the leaks tool (see my question's new screenshot) and it doesn't show me leaks from the tableview cell code. Not sure what I am missing